# Visa Denial at the US Embassy

Tags: visa-refusals

I have been denied a student visa three times within a couple of 6 months, i  was so nervous at the first appointment with the consular, so he asked for my sponsor er bank statement which was my sister and i couldn't not provide it when requested for since i did not go with it, the second appointment i can not not say precisely why i was denied a visa again. I had to write a deferment  letter to the university which was granted and they sent me a new student I-20 for the fall session 2019, i booked for the 3rd appointment in October and i was denied for the 3rd time. The consular was so mean that she asked me UN- expected questions that goes this way.

1. She started with this statement, i can see you have been denied twice while pressing her computer.
2. She did not even asked me the course i would be studying.
3. She asked me where i work.
4. How many school did i applied for
5. How did i hear about the university
6. Did i write any exams like TOEFL and rest

I guess i answered all above questions correctly

8. And so she asked me this, what has last change with me since the last time i applied , then i started explaining myself because i did not prepare myself for such question and she just cut me off and gave me blue paper again.

I am very sure i was denied because of the 8th question because she asked me that question twice and i cant even remember what i was saying since i was not preparing for such question.

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange!

Comment: While I echo @ajd's welcome, I would also note that questions about student visas are generally off topic here; [Expatriates.SE] is the more appropriate site for that.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to hear about that experience but the best advice for you is to **stop applying**. With 3 refusals in 6 months you are not going to US anytime soon.

Please accept that and move on. You're wasting your time and money and hurting your future immigration prospects. After that I would not even look for a reason it just doesn't help at that point.

As noted by @phoog below,  It may be helpful to seek help from an immigration lawyer.

Comment: If money allows, an immigration lawyer might be of use.  If the refusals are because of nerves, ineffective preparation, and the interaction of the two, a lawyer ought to be able to overcome that.  If the applicant's circumstances are inherently problematic, of course, a lawyer won't help, but a scrupulous one will say so and also advise against reapplying.

Comment: I do agree completely that a lawyer might be of help, but it looks like the OP can't afford one.